How to sleep for milliseconds before executing next command?
I want to map <a-p> to execute multicommands. However, the first command is executed asynchronously. How can I sleep for about 20 miliseconds before executing next command?
    { 
        "key": "alt+p", 
         "command": "runCommands",
         "args": {
            "commands":[
                {
                    "command":"vscode-neovim.send",
                    "args": "<a-p>", 
                },
                {
                    "command":"editor.action.formatSelection",
                }
            ]
         },
        "when": "editorTextFocus && neovim.init" 
    }

I have no idea how to achieve this.

have you looked at the extension multi-command

@rioV8 That's a solution. Is there any builtin method?
